# Check if an item is already in another Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, grid, kendo-grid

I have 3 grids in my webapplication. All the grids are filled with user data. I'm using Telerik Kendo asp.net mvc to display said grid.

What i want to achieve: In the first of the 3 grids, I want to show if there is already a duplicate entry in the second OR third grid.

For example:

1st Grid contains a user named "Max Mustermann" and 3rd Grid contains a user named "Max Mustermann" then in the 1st grid I want to make a column which says "User is already in the 3rd Grid".

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help :]

Comment: code please____

Comment: I provided client side solution, do you want a server side solution? if yes, kindly provide the models code for gird 1 and 3, and also on which fields you want to compare and which field you want to update

Comment: thank you for your fast Response.  Yes im looking for a Server side solution. 
I added the model for grid 1 and 3
i want to compare the fields "AssetOwner.Displayname"
i want to update the field "Exists" 

thank you in advance and have a great day. :]

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following

- For each item in the first Grid, try to find it in the second grid ( your case grid number 3)
- If item was found, update the required field with "User already exists", in my code I will use its name as **Status**

here your code

```
<script>
function ShowExists(){
    var firstGrid = $("#FirstGrid").data("kendoGrid");       
    var firstData = firstGrid.dataSource.data();
    var thirdGrid = $("#ThirdGrid").data("kendoGrid");       
    var thirdData = thirdGrid.dataSource.data(); 

     for(var i = 0; i<firstData.length; i++) {
            var firstItem = firstData[i];
            for(var j=0; j< thirdData.length; j++){
                    var secondItem = thirdData[j];
                     if( secondItem.User == firstItem.User){
                              firstItem.Status = "User already exists in the 3rd grid";
                              break;
                              // status is the field to show that user exists
                     }  
     }
    }
}
<script>
```

Hope this will help you